# My iphone application was rejected because I don't have a support URL

Tags: iphone, release

Foes anyone know why This is and why I need a support url?  If I don't have a web site what should I do.  Why isn't email enough?
Thanks
Saro

Comment: This question is off topic. It might be better off on [the App Stores proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make a free site on http://www.blogger.com/  (have I reached 30 characters yet?)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a web site, less customers will be interested in your app.  So get one and make it look attractive and professional.

Comment: Just curious, would a facebook page count as a website?

Comment: It should be a web page that people don't have to log in to see.  Having your company or vendor name in the URL domain name gives a much better impression to potential customers.

Comment: I don't think I have ever downloaded an application and looked at the web site.   The website is for support only.  So it is kind of weird why they would enforce it.

Comment: @Saro - Maybe not you.  But at an Apple developer presentation, Apple said that their own research showed that an attractive and informative web site increased sales.  So other potential customers do, and they don't buy apps if the developer isn't professional enough to create a proper looking web presence.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  this is just a free app i was putting out there.  Thanks for the info though.